# How to update a path having an invalid slash?

Tags: php

I have a Path which is not valid:

> `C:\xampp\htdocs\laposte\app\webroot\img/Penguins.jpg`

how to change the string having forward slashes only e.g

> `C:/xampp/htdocs/laposte/app/webroot/img/Penguins.jpg`

my idea is to extract the words out of the string and then rebuild the string with forward slash.

how do you do that?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 2):

Use [realpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function.

```
$str = realpath("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laposte\\app\\webroot\\img/Penguins.jpg");
echo $str; //C:\xampp\htdocs\laposte\app\webroot\img\Penguins.jpg
```

Or directly :

```
$str = str_replace('\\', '/', $str);
echo $str; //C:/xampp/htdocs/laposte/app/webroot/img/Penguins.jpg
```

Comment: That won't work, those ``\`` characters are escape sequences not data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your path is OK for windows, except for the last slash. It should be backslash like this:
C:\xampp\htdocs\laposte\app\webroot\img\Penguins.jpg

Comment: AFAIK most Windows file-APIs allow slashes in both directions

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use constant [**DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR**](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) rather than `/` to separate your path. It'll completely fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use string replace function in php:

```
echo str_replace("\\","/","C:\xampp\htdocs\laposte\app\webroot\img/Penguins.jpg");
```